# Angular js Input type file - clear previously selected file

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, input-type-file, angular-file-upload

I am using `input type="file"` for my upload control using angular js. Everytime I click on browse, I do not want to see the previously selected file. By default,this seems to be retained. Can it be achieved by writing a directive? Can it be triggered everytime I click on browse?

I am using a bootstrap implementation to replace default browse button with some better.

```
 <span class="useBootstrap btn btn-default btn-file">
                Browse <input type="file"  />
            </span>
```

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079779/how-to-clear-a-file-input-from-angular-js

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This was the easiest way, without using any directive or complex code.

```
Browse <input type="file" ng-click="clear()"
```

And in your controller

```
 $scope.clear = function () {
    angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
};
```

Comment: Yes, indeed this is an easiest way.... But it is not the right way. I have gone through the trouble of rewriting the whole code once again in the form of directives and all, thats why I cannot recommend this approach.

Comment: This complained that it cannot use jqLite for selectors. But this worked fine: var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#some-id' ) );

Comment: If you want a separate `Clear` or `Cancel` button, add an `id=` to the element. E.g. `id="fileSelector_1" and then `angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileSelector_1')).val(null);`  This works for me. I use it to clear on both the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons,

Answer (score 0):

```
here is alternate way to clear input file type. 
HTML ->>
`<span class="useBootstrap btn btn-default btn-file">
   Browse <input type="file" ng-if="clearBtn" />
</span>`

Js ->>

`//initial loading
$scope.clearBtn = true;
// after submit / on reset function
$scope.submitform = function(){
//submit logic goes here;
//onsuccess function
$scope.clearBtn = false;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.clearBtn = true;
  });
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use fileUpload directive, then we can clear uploaded file data directly from HTML.

e:g-

Directive -

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel)
      var modelSetter = model.assign
      element.bind('change', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0])
        })
  })
}
```

}
}])

html code- upload file input field

```
<button ng-disabled="!myFile" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-ef btn-        
ef-5 btn-ef-5a mb-10 "
ng-click="uploadFile(myFile);myFile=''">Upload button
</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5a mb-10 "
ng-click="myFile=''">Clear
</button>
```

call http service

```
  var fd = new FormData()
   fd.append('file', file) //File is from uploadFile(myFile)

   $http.post(url, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined,
          'sessionId': sessionId,
          'project': userProject
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily, here's an example:

```
   <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" id="fileInp" required file-input="files" >
```

//in my code the rest happens when a response is sent from the server

```
  $http.post('upload.php', form_data,
       {

            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
       }).success(function(response){
        $scope.response_msg=response;
           if($scope.response_msg=="File Uploaded Successfully")
           {
            $scope.IsVisibleSuccess = $scope.IsVisibleSuccess = true;
           }
           else
           {
            $scope.IsVisibleFailed=$scope.IsVisibleFailed=true;
           }


                  $scope.img_name='';


                 $("input[type='file']").val('');

       });
```